# Write custom query to fetch wordpress data/Creating JSON using wordpress tables

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, wordpress

I want to fetch the data in my WordPress site and display it in android using JSON. My problem is I don't get how I get the particular posts data with all Images in that post using the custom QUERY and convert it into JSON using PHP.

My site have some custom post types example portfolio, I also want to fetch all data for portfolio item.

If you have any ideas or solutions for my problem please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API in the works for WordPress that outputs JSON.

Currently it is a plugin, but its future is to be integrated into core.

Development
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API

Beta Releases
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Documentation
http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Open WP Rest Api plugin with plugin editor and add this code in your plugin file;

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_portfolios' );
function register_my_portfolios() {
    $args = array(
      'public'       => false,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'label'        => 'Portfolios'
    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );
}
```

now you can query your portfolio post types